# how to fixed this ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5, angular12

Why is the categoryJobLists.length given the error **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')**

```
<ion-content>

  <div *ngIf="categoryJobLists && categoryJobLists.length > 0">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let categorysJobs of categoryJobLists">
        <ion-col size="6" (click)="openJobDetailPage(categoryJobLists)">
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-header>
              <ion-card-title> {{categorysJobs.job_title}} </ion-card-title>
              <ion-card-subtitle>Total Opening:  {{categorysJobs.total_vacancies}} </ion-card-subtitle>
            </ion-card-header>
          
            <ion-card-content>
              Open from  {{categorysJobs.apply_from_date}}
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="categoryJobLists && categoryJobLists.length == 0">
    <ion-chip>
      <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Not Found</ion-label>
    </ion-chip>
  </div>
  
</ion-content>
```

[image: Please see this attach Image]

Comment: Please click on `template.html:33` in the stack trace to see which expression is causing the issue and share it. Maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: check only '*ngIf="categoryJobLists"'

Comment: Please post the entire code, because we can't see line 33.
Also try and open your application in a different browser. I had a similar error where Chrome and Firefox disagreed where the error was. Firefox turned out to be the most precise.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ion-content>
    
      <div *ngIf="categoryJobLists && categoryJobLists?.length > 0">
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row *ngFor="let categorysJobs of categoryJobLists">
            <ion-col size="6" (click)="openJobDetailPage(categoryJobLists)">
              <ion-card>
                <ion-card-header>
                  <ion-card-title> {{categorysJobs?.job_title}} </ion-card-title>
                  <ion-card-subtitle>Total Opening:  {{categorysJobs?.total_vacancies}} </ion-card-subtitle>
                </ion-card-header>
              
                <ion-card-content>
                  Open from  {{categorysJobs?.apply_from_date}}
                </ion-card-content>
              </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </div>

  <div *ngIf="categoryJobLists && categoryJobLists?.length == 0">
    <ion-chip>
      <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Not Found</ion-label>
    </ion-chip>
  </div>
  
</ion-content>
```

change your current code just like this and add a property in your **.ts** file

---

```
export class ListJobPage implements OnInit {
categoryJobLists: any = [];
  constructor( ) { }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

---

like this...

*This issue has occurred, you must have added the '**categoryJobLists**' property in your **.ts file** as like ...*

```
categoryJobLists: any;
```

**You must be added 'categoryJobLists' as an array, then only we can take the array length, and if we had declared 'categoryJobLists' as 'any', then it is not much specific.**